# Why am i getting the "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" error with Supplier?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, try-catch, supplier

I get the error with the following code:

```
private Supplier<ProfileData > expectedValidProfileData = () -> {
    try {
        ProfileData profileData = new ProfileData ();
        return profileData ;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return null;
};
```

I'm not sure why though, because if I copied the code directly from another file where the error isn't present

I noticed that I don't get the error if I remove the try-catch statements

Comment: you are not returning anything in case an exception is thrown

Comment: It looks like you can't handle the exception. Just don't catch it. Or if you have to, rethrow it as a RuntimeException.

Comment: do you really need try catch ?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox a lambda won't compile if there is an unhandled checked exception...

Comment: Adding a return statement to the catch block didn't fix the issue

Comment: If I see correctly, the code in the question has been corrected meanwhile, which means that this thread is quite confusing to read now. But even in the original form there shouldn't be a syntax error reported. What exact code location did this error message refer to?

Comment: @Andrew_Tobilko that's why I said rethrow as a RuntimeException... I tried to make my answer a little more generic

Answer (score 2):

add return statement in catch part (exception as per need) that's why it is working without try-catch block

```
private Supplier<ProfileData > expectedValidProfileData = () -> {
    try {
        ProfileData profileData = new ProfileData ();
        return profileData ;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         //add return statement here
         return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. And the code I copied doesn't have a return statement in its catch block, and it isn't throwing an error

Comment: Hello @klippy, After adding return statement are you facing the same error or something new is there, there might be some other case from where you have copied,

Comment: @klippy Also make sure you have added return statement for other methods if any

Comment: You're trying to fix a semantic error, but the question is about a *Syntax error* (at unknown position).